# How to display profile picture on external website

Tags: session

I'm trying to display the profile picture on another website (photo url is something like `https://c.na87.content.force.com/profilephoto/1234W000000ABCD/F`. I have a `sid` token returned by oauth.

There's that url hack that lets you pass session id as a query string parameter and also pass a `retURL` path that might be a photo url, like:

```
https://[instance].salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=[SESSION_ID]?retURL=https://c.na87.content.force.com/profilephoto/1234W000000ABCD/F
```

Which seems to work, but only if the users don't use lightning and only as a browser redirect - so it doesn't work in `img src`.

SFDC session system creates separate `sid` for each domain, thus `*.content.force.com` - in which profile photo lives - has its own `sid`. Using this session id as below seems to do the trick, but I have no idea how to obtain that session id (headless browser login or copy and paste the cookie doesn't count)

```
https://c.na87.content.force.com/profilephoto/1234W000000ABCD/F?sid=[SESSION_ID_FOR_.content.force.com_DOMAIN]
```

Any ideas?